# How to combine datasets of 2 different datasources in iReport 4.7

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have 2 **Datasources** A and B. I have 2 **Datasets** 'a' and 'b' respectively from them.

I need to use datasets 'a' and 'b' and generate a report from them. [i.e, Create a table and use the fields from both dataset 'a' and dataset 'b']

I **cannot** use a subreport or a jar.

Is there a way in ***iReport*** to acheive my requirement?

I am using Ireport 4.7.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Ireport 4.7 what you can do, create two datasets as you have done already and use two table element side by side, then only you can show two fields from different datasets.

Comment: Thanks I have implemented on similar lines.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do this in reports in JaseperReports Server 4.7. 2 Datasets can be used for 2 different graphical widgets separately.

JasperReports Server 5.0 allows you to create domains based on multiple datasources, which may accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely look into it. Since I am using a lower version of the report server, as a work around I have implemented  on similar lines as posted by Sharad below.